Rails Devise LDAP - Signed Connection Question
I have a rails app that has been using devise / devise_ldap_authenticatable for years to authenticate to AD. The logins started failing and I am seeing LDAP error 8: Stronger auth needed. in the logs.
Talking to my IT they said all ldap connections had to be signed.
I am not sure how/where to configure this. Is this a devise thing? A machine thing? Has anyone ever gone through this?
Any info is appreciated.

In your ldap.yaml have whats the value for the ssl attribute for the provider you are using ? it should be true if you want the requests to be signed.

# config/ldap.ymldevelopment:
  host: 
  port: 
  attribute: 
  base: 
  admin_user: 
  admin_password:
  ssl: true


Thanks! Referring to it as a signed connection threw me off. Everything I looked on signed connections I found little to nothing with devise.
